# Fast floating point modpow

Tags: python, math, floating-point, exponentiation, modulo

I am looking to compute a^b mod m where a & b are **floating point** numbers and m is an non-negative integer. The trivial solution is to do b multiplications which takes O(n) time, however my numbers a & b can be largish (~10 digits before the decimal point) and I would like to do this efficiently. When a,b and m are integers we can compute the modpow quickly in log(n) time via: [Exponentiation_by_squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

How would I use this method (or another) for floating point numbers? I am using Python to do this computation and the pow function only allows integers. Here is my attempt at doing exponentiation by squaring with Decimal numbers, but the answer is not coming out right:

```
from decimal import Decimal

EPS = Decimal("0.0001")

# a, b are Decimals and m is an integer
def deci_pow(a, b, m):
  if abs(b) < EPS:
    return Decimal(1)
  tmp = deci_pow(a, b / 2, m) % m # Should this be // ?
  if abs(b % 2) < EPS:
    return (tmp * tmp) % m
  else:
    if b > 0:
      return (a * tmp * tmp) % m
    else:
      return ((tmp * tmp)/a) % m

print(deci_pow(Decimal(2.4), Decimal(3.5), 5)) # != 1.416
```

When a,b,m are all integers this is what the method looks like:

```
# a, b, m are Integers
def integer_pow(a, b, m):
  if b == 0: return 1
  tmp = integer_pow(a, b // 2, m) % m
  if b % 2 == 0:
    return (tmp * tmp) % m
  else:
    if b > 0:
      return (a * tmp * tmp) % m
    else:
      return ((tmp * tmp) / a) % m
```

Comment: You mean (a**b)mod m? And how did you get 4.705 in your example?

Comment: Sorry about that, human error. The actual answer should be 1.416!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this in general, if `a` and `b` can be 10 digits (assuming before the decimal point). The problem is that for floats `x` and `y`, you don't necessarily have the property

```
((x % m) * (y % m)) % m == (x * y) % m
```

If you tell us your specific context and why you want to do this, there might be other approaches possible.